# Portal for users with no authentication

Tags: visualforce, customer-portal, customer-community, partner-portal, public

Is it possible to create a "contact us" public facing webpage that requires no authentication?

I'd like to have the public-user go to a public page, fill out minor details, click Contact Us which then triggers a workflow *or something* to log their details in Salesforce for internal-users to follow up with clients.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible with [force.com sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Sites) .

With force.com sites you can build visualforce pages that can be accessed by an anonymous user .

The other option is to configure a simple web to Lead form  your SFDC instance ,where from your website you can capture the leads and have an internal process for creating community users .

Comment: any ideas on the cost of sites.com?

Comment: also, is there any other free-er ways to do this?  Perhaps with using API calls?

Comment: for cost you will need to contact SFDC ..If you have SFDC instance already with you sites are free

Comment: I have an org with 16 unlimited licenses and a customer community

Comment: Yes you will have sites activated for free then